# How to update firebase data node from a new activity when child is random key generated by current date and current time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please see my code and snapshot what I am looking for, I created a new activity from where I can update my product details (*note:I will add image upload functionality later in my activity*). but from my code I get the result like the snapshot I attached where I marked in red what I wanted. I add products as admin and trying to update as admin but from a different activity I wanted to update my data. Please help me

Here is activity code I am trying

[image]

```js
package com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.ViewHolder.ProductViewHolder;
import com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.model.Products;
import com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.prevalent.prevalent;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class AdminUpdatingProductsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String UpdateDescription, updatePrice, updatePName;
    private TextView updateTxtBtn, changeImageTxt, closeTxtBtn;
    private EditText productUpdateName, productUpdateDescription, productUpdatePrice;

    private DatabaseReference updateProductRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_updating_products);

        updateProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

        updateTxtBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.update_product_details_btn2);
        changeImageTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_image_update_txt);
        closeTxtBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.close_update_product_btn);
        productUpdateName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_product_name);
        productUpdateDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_product_description);
        productUpdatePrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_product_price);


        updateTxtBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                updateinformation();
            }
        });

    }

    private void updateinformation() {

        updatePName = productUpdateName.getText().toString();
        UpdateDescription = productUpdateDescription.getText().toString();
        updatePrice = productUpdatePrice.getText().toString();

        HashMap<String, Object> ProductMap = new HashMap<>();
        ProductMap.put("pname", updatePName);
        ProductMap.put("price", updatePrice);
        ProductMap.put("description", UpdateDescription);

        updateProductRef.updateChildren(ProductMap);

    }
   }
```

And here is xml :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.AdminUpdatingProductsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_update_product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tollbar_update_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/close_update_product_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Close"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/update_product_details_btn2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Update"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image_update"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_update_product"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_image_update_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_image_update"
        android:text="Change Image"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/update_product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_image_update_txt"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:hint="Product Name..."
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_design"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/update_product_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/update_product_name"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:hint="Product Description..."
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_design"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/update_product_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/update_product_description"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:hint="Product Price..."
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_design"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```js
package com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.Interface.ItemClickListner;
import com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.ViewHolder.ProductViewHolder;
import com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.model.Products;
import com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.prevalent.prevalent;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class AdminListedProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private DatabaseReference AdminProductsRef;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_listed_product);




        AdminProductsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.productlist_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
                        .setQuery(AdminProductsRef, Products.class)
                        .build();




        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder>(options)
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Products model)
                    {

                        holder.txtProductName.setText(model.getPname());
                        holder.txtProductDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
                        holder.txtProductPrice.setText("Price = "+ model.getPrice());
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);


                        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                        {
                                                "Edit",
                                                "Remove"
                                        };

                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminListedProductActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("Edit/Delete");
                                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                    {


                                        if(which == 0)
                                        {
                                            
                                          updateProducts();

                                        }

                                        if(which == 1)
                                        {
                                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products")
                                                    .child(model.getDate() + model.getTime())
                                                    .removeValue()
                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                                        {
                                                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                                                            {
                                                                Toast.makeText(AdminListedProductActivity.this, "Item Removed Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminListedProductActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class);
                                                                startActivity(intent);

                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                builder.show();

                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items_layout, parent, false);
                        ProductViewHolder holder = new ProductViewHolder(view);
                        return  holder;

                    }
                };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();


    }

    private void updateProducts()
    {

        finish();



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
         super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

and here is my Products Class under a package named model

```js
package com.commerce.daily.dailycommerce.model;

/**
 * Created by Romen on 2/10/2019.
 */

public class Products
{
    private String pname, description, price,image, category, pid, date, time;

    public Products()
    {

    }

    public Products(String pname, String description, String price, String image, String category, String pid, String date, String time)
    {
        this.pname = pname;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
        this.category = category;
        this.pid = pid;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the specific node which you want in this way, Because you didn't specify which node you want to update its data.
in this line `updateProductRef.updateChildren(ProductMap);` you specify the "product" node then add data inside it, instead of that you should specify the node that you want to update it.

to achieve this you should put a unique id for each node (like "pid" attribute in your database), then compare it with the "pid" in your current activity.

1. in your class "products" put getter and setter methods for the "pid" attribute.
2. when clicking on the special product from your list that contains all "products" get the position of the item and get "pid" from it, like this:
3. after getting the current item of "pid" send it with the intent by using the `putExtra()` method on the intent object to the new activity.
4. catch the string that sent from previous activity and comare it with all `pid` attributes that in the database, then get key to the product and set as a child.

**Edit**

actually, I don't understand your code correctly or it is a mistake so, I build another code totally different.

- create an adapter class for display products:

`public class AdapterProducts extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProducts.HolderProuducts> {
    Context context;
    List<products> listProuducts;`

```
private AdapterProducts.OnItemClickListener mListener;

//This interface for handle clicked on an item in recyclerview
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterProducts.OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

//constrouctor
public AdapterProducts(Context context,List<products> listProuducts)
{
    this.listProuducts = listProuducts;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public AdapterProducts.HolderProuducts onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_item_products, viewGroup, false);
    AdapterProducts.HolderProuducts holder = new AdapterProducts.HolderProuducts(row, mListener);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterProducts.HolderProuducts holderProuducts, int i) {

    holderProuducts.txtProductName.setText(model.getPname());
    holderProuducts.txtProductDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
    holderProuducts.txtProductPrice.setText("Price = "+ model.getPrice());
    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holderProuducts.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listProuducts.size();
}

public class HolderProuducts extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView txtProductName,txtProductDescription,txtProductPrice;
    ImageView imageView;

    public HolderProuducts(@NonNull View itemView, final AdapterProducts.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        txtProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_product);
        txtProductDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_product);
        txtProductPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_product);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

}

- in your `AdminListedProductActivity`:

  `

public class AdminListedProductActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerProducts;
List<Products> listProducts;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
AdapterProducts mAdapterProducts;

DatabaseReference AdminProductsRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_listed_product);

    AdminProductsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");


    listProducts = new ArrayList();
    mRecyclerProducts = findViewById(R.id.productlist_recycler);
    mRecyclerProducts.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerProducts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    listProducts = displayProuductsInList();

    mAdapterProducts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterProducts.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Products productsClicked = listProducts.get(position);

            //This pid for the item that clicked on it
            String pid = productsClicked.getPid();

            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminListedProductActivity .this,AdminUpdatingProductsActivity.class);

            //send it with intent to activity update
            intent.putExtra("pid",pid);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

//This method for get all products from database
private List<Products> displayProuductsInList() {
    List<Products> list = new ArrayList();

    AdminProductsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Products products = data.getValue(Products.class);
                list.add(products);
            }
            mRecyclerProducts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(AdminListedProductActivity .this));
            mAdapterProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

}
`

in your `AdminUpdatingProductsActivity`:

```
public class AdminUpdatingProductsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String UpdateDescription, updatePrice, updatePName;
private TextView updateTxtBtn, changeImageTxt, closeTxtBtn;
private EditText productUpdateName, productUpdateDescription, productUpdatePrice;

DatabaseReference updateProductRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_listed_product);

    updateProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

    updateTxtBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.update_product_details_btn2);
    changeImageTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_image_update_txt);
    closeTxtBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.close_update_product_btn);
    productUpdateName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_product_name);
    productUpdateDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_product_description);
    productUpdatePrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_product_price);


    updateTxtBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            updateinformation();
        }
    });
}


private void updateinformation() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String pidFromPriveosActivity = intent.getStringExtra("pid");

    updatePName = productUpdateName.getText().toString();
    UpdateDescription = productUpdateDescription.getText().toString();
    updatePrice = productUpdatePrice.getText().toString();

    HashMap<String, Object> ProductMap = new HashMap<>();
    ProductMap.put("pname", updatePName);
    ProductMap.put("price", updatePrice);
    ProductMap.put("description", UpdateDescription);

    updateProductRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        String currentKey;

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                //get each "pid" in database for all products
                String pidsInDataBase = data.child("pid").getValue(String.class);

                //compare "pid" from previous activity with each "pid" in database
                if (pidFromPriveosActivity.equals(pidsInDataBase)){

                    //get key for product that clicke on it in recyclerview
                    currentKey = data.getKey();
                }
            }

            //update data for this item
            updateProductRef.child(currentKey).updateChildren(ProductMap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know after trying this, also I have already Products class and getter and setter for "pid".... Thanks again

Comment: please can you show me full code as I am new and I could not solve this cause I am getting code error ... please see my another activity and model class I updated in above. @Amr Jyniat

Comment: hI, @Amr Jyniat Thanks a lot..... I could not express that how I can tell you Thank you cause I solve it... just needed to change few code String currentPid = i.getStringExtra("pid"); and I didnt need to use Products productClicked = listOfproducts.get(position);

Comment: If this answer is correct make sure you mark it please.

Comment: Sorry to say I didnt notice that when I use that code and I try to update all 3 nodes its crash my apps and blink my database.... so finaly I could not succed. but Thanks for your help... if you can see my all code I updated and let me have a full code solution may be I am getting error in my coding

Comment: I still see your code ` updateProductRef.updateChildren(ProductMap)`, you did not update it correctly! like this:                                 ` updateProductRef.child(key).updateChildren(ProductMap)`

Comment: @ Amr Jyniat please can you copy all of my code and give me fresh code updating where necessary.... please I am giving you trouble never mind I am new and I have no experience to understand everything.... plz plz if you can do it for me

Comment: Ok, let me know whether this scenario correct for your app or not.

you have an activity display all products in Recyclerview, then, when you clicked on an item in it, it will open another activity to change/update this item.


this scenario right?

Comment: @ Amr Jyniat thanks a lot for your time... I will apply it and let you know